# Jpa cascade insert: unnecessary update?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, cascade

I have a parent entity with an auto-generated ID and it contains a collection of children entities

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID_permesso")
private Integer iDpermesso;
...
@JoinColumn(...)
@OneToMany(...)
List<ChildEntity> ChildrenList;
```

The one to many relationship is unidirectional so the child entity has the following integer field:

```
@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "ID_permesso")
private Integer iDpermesso;
```

I read the article [The best way to map a @OneToMany relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), section **Unidirectional @OneToMany with @JoinColumn** and obtained the same results with EclipseLink.

Inserting the parent entity the following database operations are performed:

```
insert into parent table
read the auto-generated ID
for every child in the list 
    insert into the child table with ID_permesso set to null
    read the auto-generated ID
for every child in the list  
    update the child with the correct ID_permesso
```

According to the above article the only way to avoid these updates is to use bidirectional relationship. The auto-generated ID for the parent is already known to JPA when children are inserted into the db, so I cannot understand why **ID_permesso** is set to null instead of the correct value.

There is another consequence, database integrity constraints should be relaxed: the foreign key **ID_permesso** on the children table must be nullable or the transaction will be aborted.

Comment: *The one to many relationship is unidirectional so the child entity has the following integer field* Why does the child entity have that field? It is not required. How are you managing the value of that field as there is nothing in your mappings that makes it  dependent on the parent entity?

Comment: Don't think the behavior I'm complaining about, an update of the foreign key after having inserted it with a null value, is related to the presence of that integer field. I believe I 'm going to use  bidirectional relationship as suggested in the linked article, otherwise the only way to preserve not null constraint on the foreign key is to persit the children 'by hand' assigning the right value to its  **ID_permesso**.